# Regex to match patterns of same numbers

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been trying to concoct a regex that searches for patterns in numbers. For example, the regex should pull 1725648 out of 172564817256481725648.

Currently, I've got
`(\\d+){1+}`, but it's just returning blank.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're going to find a regex to do that. You need more powerful mechanisms to do what you're looking for, one such is the [Robin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

This will work on your example

```
^(\d+)\1+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30q9v)

You can get the found pattern from group 1.

This will match sequences of the same digit sequence. `\1` is a backreference to what is matched in `(\d+)`. I put a `+` behind it, so it would need to match this sequence till the end. `^` anchors it to the start of the string and `$` to the end.

But your requirements are not very clear. [See this](http://regexr.com?30qa2)

```
(\d+).*\1
```

It is missing the anchors and allows stuff `.*` in between searched pattern. But it will find only the first sequence in string, that is repeated later in the string.

```
Hello1725648Foo987Bar987Foobar1725648  
     |||||||__________________|||||||
```

it will find `1725648`

```
He987llo1725648FooBar987Foobar1725648
  |||________________|||
```

it will find `987`

```
123He987llo1725648FooBar987Foobar1725648
|________________________________|
```

it will find only `1`